# CYPRESS - Cant make a THEN => IF VISIBLE statement

Tags: if-statement, testing, null, cypress, visible

okay,

here is the situation:

On a test I'm doing on a website, it always has a table, but when that table has no elements it is hidden. I need to perform an action only if that table has visible elements. And if not, just continue to the next tests.

So, if for example, the table is empty, and I write this --- cy.get('element', {timeout: 60000}).should('be.visible') --- The test times out, which is correct, since the table is empty and therefore wont become visible.

But, of course, I need the test NOT TO timeout, I need that after the stipulated time has passed, it continues to the next tests.

So, I thought of this:

---

```
cy.get('element').then(($table) => {  
    if ($table.is(':visible')){
        cy.log('JUST TESTING')
    }
})
```

---

Problem is, it always enter the if and print the console log JUST TESTING. That means that the if visible condition is not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you have two cases to test, one if the table has elements and one if the table has no elements. I would split this into two test cases and populate/not populate the table so it either shows or doesn't show. IMHO, doing this in one test case doesn't prove the the table is working or not working as how do you know what you are seeing is correct. You could have the situation where the table should be showing as it has content, but doesn't, but you're test will always pass as it doesn't know what the state of the table should be. So something like...

```
describe('Testing my table', () => {
  context('table is populated', () => {
  beforeEach {
  // populate the table with data
  }
  it('should show the table, () => {
    // Some testing stuff in here to check the table is showing
  });

  context('table is NOT populated', () => {
  beforeEach {
  // Any set up you need for a non-populated table
  }
  it('shouldn't show the table, () => {
    // Check we can't see the table
  });
```